# Peering two sites in a VPN: DIY mode with twin Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have two sites, A and B, like shown in the diagram below

```
+-+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| |            |OTHER DEVICES                                        |
| |            |:-)                    SITE A: 128.66.32.0/24  |     |
| |            +-------+               PUBLIC DNS: SITEA.EXAMPLE.ORG |
| |            |       |               PORT FORWARDING CUSTOMIZABLE  |
| |            |       |               DYNAMIC IP / DDNS             |
| +------------+       |                                             |
|                      |                                             |
| +---------------+----+-------------------+---------+-------------+ |
|                 |                        |         |               |
|  RASPBERRY PI   |         PRINTER        |         |    ROUTER/GW  |
|  128.66.32.18   |         128.66.32.3    |         |    128.66.32.1|
| +------------+  |        +----------+    |         |    +----------+
| |            |  |        |          |    |         |    |          |
| |            |  |        |          |    |         |    |          |
| |            +--+        |          +----+         +----+          |
| |            |           |          |                   |          |
+-+------------+-----------+----------+-------------------+----------+






 +-----------------------------+-------------+------------+----------+
 |  SITE B: 128.66.55.0/24     |             |            |          |
 |  NO DNS                     |             |            |          |
 |  FIREWALLED BY ISP    +-----+             |        +---+          |
 |  DYNAMIC IP           |     +-------------+        |   |          |
 |  PUBLIC IP 10.0.0.0/8 |      LAPTOP                |   |          |
 |                       |      DHCP                  |   +----------+
 |                       |                            |   ROUTER/GW  |
 |                       |                            |   128.66.55.1|
 |                       |                            |              |
 |  ++-------------------+-------------------+--------+-----------+  |
 |   |                                       |                       |
 |   |                                       |                       |
 |   |   NAS                                 |      RASPBERRY PI     |
 |   |   128.66.55.23                        |      128.66.55.18     |
 |   |  +-------------+                      |      +-----------+    |
 |   |  |             |                      |      |           |    |
 |   +--+             |                      +------+           |    |
 |      |             |                             |           |    |
 +------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----+
```

What I basically want is to **peerly** connect the two sites. A VPN can allow me to access any host within A while being in B.
In theory, a VPN link established between A and B should allow any device in A to type `ping 128.66.55.x` and see data.

Since I have two spare Raspberry Pi machines I want to unleash them and establish a permanent and **transparent** VPN link, so anybody will get a zero-configuration link between the two sites.

As you have seen, one of the sites is not addressable: can work only as a client because ISP provides a private IP address shared among several customers.

### Homework I did

I have examined [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) documentation and got an idea on how to configure the `Pi`s one as server and one as client. Then while I wait for traveling to A to deploy the Raspberry server and port-forward it, I have other oubts. I will be ready to leave an SSH channel open to administer the Raspberry while I'm out.

### Pending questions:

I am a bit rusty about networking, as I attended classes many years ago.

- Can OpenVPN be used for peering two sites in a VPN? Or am I following the wrong path?
- I know I need to have a routing rule between `eth0` and `tun` adapters on both devices. Does OpenVPN do it for me or do I need to use iptables?
- In order to make the VPN transparent, I don't remember if I have to set a static route on the main gateways (e.g. route 128.66.55.0/24 via 128.66.32.18) **or** the Raspberries should broadcast the route within their `eth0` network. Which of the two?

Basically I need to remotely print, access NAS and so on

Comment: Here is how I do it on my RPi linux server, it isn't exactly what you want, but it might help you or others: My 404 page pings my other servers, and if it founds the failed directory, it redirects to that (and creates a fake directory with PHP redirection, so it only pings once if it exists). This is a bad approach, but it works, and it is just intranet of our home network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I was correct in my design and on the good way. I am now answering my own question both to share knowledge **and** publish my thoughts, research and considerations for reference in future questions.

Thanks to [this post](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans) I have found most of the answers to my questions. So let me summarize:

- OpenVpn has setup for peering LANs

> Our user had a openvpn server with a lan (10.10.2.0/24) behind it,
>   and 2 client with lans behind them:
>
> client1 with lan 10.10.1.0/24 client2 with lan 10.10.3.0/24
>
> He wanted machines on all 3 lans to be able to communicate using a tun
>   (routed) setup.
>
> Every machine with a LAN behind it must have IP forwarding enabled. In
>   this example that means the server, and client1/client2. The user
>   needed the following in his server.conf:

```
route 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.10.3.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.10.2.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.3.0 255.255.255.0"
client-to-client
```

Simply need to adapt to my case: Server has to `route` only the networks it does not control, and `push` all. It's not so smart to dynamically push every LAN that connects to it. Not a problem because I am not implementing a scalable setup and I have only two LANs

- OpenVpn takes care of routing on the Raspberry it's running on.

I have made an example within my own lan at B site. I assigned an A's IP address to Raspberry A, let her take a DHCP address from B on the same `eth0` interface and then run both OpenVpn and an echo server. Then I connected Raspberry A, who had her B network IP address, to Raspberry A's address in B LAN.
Finally, I could echo and watch it in the logs. Only caveat was that Raspberry A (echo server) saw connection from an IP in A range and not in B, so the LANs were not communicating.

- Routes must be set at gateway, apparently. The article explains it well. Let me quote

> Lets say our server is 10.10.2.10 on its lan, and uses 10.10.2.1 as
>   its default route, and you want the 2.x lan to be accessible or able
>   to access over the vpn. 2.1 would need a route for every network that
>   2.x will access or be accessed by. That means in our example: 10.10.2.1 must know that for 10.10.1.x 10.10.3.x and the vpn internal network (for example, 10.8.0.x), it sends the traffic to 10.10.2.10
>   This is true for any number of lans you want to connect, whether
>   server or client.
>
> If you fail to add this route, here is what would happen if a VPN
>   client (for example, 10.8.0.6) wanted to send traffic to 10.10.2.20:
>
> ```
> The vpn client sends traffic to 10.10.2.20, with a source address of 10.8.0.6
> The vpn server (10.8.0.1 and 10.10.2.10) receives the traffic, has IP forwarding enabled, and passes the traffic to 10.10.2.20
> 10.10.2.20 gets it and tries to respond to 10.8.0.6 but has no entry in its routing table
> Because 10.10.2.20 has no route for 10.8.0.6, it sends the traffic to its default gateway which is 10.10.2.1
> 10.10.2.1 checks its routing table, has no route for 10.8.0.6, and sends the traffic to its default gateway which is likely its ISP
> The ISP ignores it, because it is a RFC 1918 ip (aka lan only)
> ```

Since I happen to have control on both gateways, setting a static route was the correct way